# How to form dynamic key value array inside meta_query wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my meta query

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'auto',
    'meta_query' => array(          
        array(
            'key'     => 'a',
            'value'   => 'test', 
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'b',
            'value'   => 'test', 
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'c',
            'value'   => '', 
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'd',
            'value'   => '', 
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'e',
            'value'   => '', 
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'f',
            'value'   => '', 
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'g',
            'value'   => '', 
        ),

    ),
);
```

I need to form the array dynamically like if array values of certain key is null then it should not be appended to the meta query.

Example in the above array key 'c' value is null so it should not be there in the meta query like wise i have more list of key values pairs , any help is appreciated , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array_filter with callback function cleaning every array item which is null, and then pass the resultant array to `$args` array then pass to `WP_QUERY`.

Below example will clean array if its value is null, Note i've used `'relation' =>'AND'` for multiple parameters. you can check [**meta_query docs**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) in detail if you want to use `OR` statement.

```
function clean_array(&$rows)
{
    if (!empty($rows['value'])) {
        return $rows;
    }
}

$array = array(
    array('key' => 'a', 'value' => 'test'),
    array('key' => 'b', 'value' => 'test'),
    array('key' => 'c', 'value' => ''),
    array('key' => 'd', 'value' => ''),
    array('key' => 'e', 'value' => ''),
    array('key' => 'f', 'value' => ''),
    array('key' => 'g', 'value' => ''),
);

$meta_query = array_filter($array, 'clean_array');

echo '<pre>';print_r($meta_query);echo '</pre>';

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'auto',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        $meta_query
    )
);

$post = new WP_Query($args);

// below line will print query run against your parameters.
echo '<pre>';print_r($post->request);echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter_meta_query($value)
{
    return !empty($value['value']);
}

$args['meta_query'] = array_filter($args['meta_query'],'filter_meta_query');
```

Or using anonymous function if PHP 5.3 or higher.

```
$args['meta_query'] = array_filter($args['meta_query'],function($value){
   return !empty($value['value']);
});
```